# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a section for Slideshow of images in my page!! I've written its HTML, CSS and Javascript for it as well, however when I run it in chrome, I get this javascript error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined**

showSlides @slideshow.js:24

(anonymous function)@slideshow.js:2

The slideshow frame is working and visible, but the first image of the slideshow is not appearing automatically. I have to click the forward or reverse buttons to actually view the pictures!! i m guessing its because of this javascript error

**Can Anyone help me fix this Javascript Error??**

Here are the codes of my HTML, CSS and Javascript file:

HTML part:

```
<div class="slideShow" style="height: 700px;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Data/Scripts/Java/slideshow.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 9</div>
<center>
<img src="../Data/Images/iphone7_plusReview/img_01.jpg">
</center>
<div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">2 / 9</div>
<center>
<img src="../Data/Images/iphone7_plusReview/img_02.jpg">
</center>
<div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 9</div>
<center>
<img src="../Data/Images/iphone7_plusReview/img_03.jpg">
</center>
<div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">4 / 9</div>
<center>
<img src="../Data/Images/iphone7_plusReview/img_04.jpg">
</center>
<div class="text">Caption Four</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">5 / 9</div>
<center>
<img src="../Data/Images/iphone7_plusReview/img_05.jpg">
</center>
<div class="text">Caption Five</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">6 / 9</div>
<center>
<img src="../Data/Images/iphone7_plusReview/img_06.jpg">
</center>
<div class="text">Caption Six</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">7 / 9</div>
<center>
<img src="../Data/Images/iphone7_plusReview/img_07.jpg">
</center>
<div class="text">Caption Seven</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">8 / 9</div>
<center>
<img src="../Data/Images/iphone7_plusReview/img_08.jpg">
</center>
<div class="text">Caption Eight</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">9 / 9</div>
<center>
<img src="../Data/Images/iphone7_plusReview/img_09.png">
</center>
<div class="text">Caption Nine</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span> 
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span> 
</div>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1010px;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

And my slideshow.js Javascript file which supposedly has errors as chrome says

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Chrome says i have error at line no. 2 & 24, but i don't understand what is the error?? **Can some please help me fix this error?** Any help will be gladly appreciated :)

Comment: element `slides[slideIndex-1]` from line 24 not exist, console is saying you that can't read/change style of element that not exist.

Comment: Any idea where to declare that?? inside my function or outside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Actually didn't found the solution, but my main issue was, all images of the slideshow should be loaded automatically when the page loads, not not by using the previous and next buttons!!

I figured out that my Functions were not loaded automatically when the page loaded and need a call to load them, such as using the previous and next buttons.

So i fixed it using

```
<body onLoad="showSlides(); viewSlides();">
```

The onLoad property loads my functions right from the start and all images are loaded automatically after this.

I still couldn't solve that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" javascript error, but my both of my slideshows and thier scripts are running fine and so i m content with it

Thank you to all those who tried to help me, nevertheless my problem was different and had a different solution to it.

Comment: You should always post the code that helped you while self-answering a question. In your case, you must share what is `viewSlides()` to help other users.